# Is there a better way to compose this in a point-free way?

Tags: functional-programming

I come across this use-case at work all the time and I feel like there must be a way to compose fullName in a point-free way without defining cat as a parameter:

```js
    const cats = [
      { name: 'Bob', lastName: 'Ross' },
      { name: 'Frank', lastName: 'Langella' },
    ];
    
    // this bugs me
    const fullName = cat => add(
      prop('name', cat),
      prop('lastName', cat)
    );
    
    const isEqual = curry((a, b) => a === b);
    const isBobRoss = compose(isEqual('BobRoss'), fullName);
```

edit: some of the helpers above in case it helps understand the challenge

```js
/**
 *  compose :: ((a -> b), (b -> c),  ..., (y -> z)) -> a -> z
 */
const compose = (...fns) => (...args) => 
  fns.reduceRight((res, fn) => [fn.call(null, ...res)], args)[0];

/**
 *  curry :: ((a, b, ...) -> c) -> a -> b -> ... -> c
 */
function curry(fn) {
  const arity = fn.length;

  return function $curry(...args) {
    if (args.length < arity) {
      return $curry.bind(null, ...args);
    }

    return fn.call(null, ...args);
  };

/**
 *  add :: a -> b -> a + b
 */
const add = curry((x, y) =>  x + y)

/**
 *  prop :: String -> Object -> a
 */
const prop = curry((p, obj) => obj[p])
}
```

Comment: What are `add`, `prop`, `curry` and `compose`? Are you using a specific library (or your own)?

Comment: generic versions, I'll add them

Answer (score 2):

This is no exactly function composition, but sure you can write a helper function for it. [Ramda does know it as `converge`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#converge), here's a simplified (unary) version of it:

```
const converge = (fn, wraps) => arg => fn(...wraps.map(wrap => wrap(arg)));

cost fullName = converge(add, [prop('name'), prop('lastName')]);
```

Answer (score 2):

(Initially I decline to commit to a specific functional programming library for JS/TS and work in general concepts)

Notice that your curred `prop` function takes a key and returns a reader monad. This will be useful.

Assuming `type Obj = {name:string,lastName:string}`, then your curried prop fn is `(key:'name'|'lastName') => Reader<Obj,string>`

You can use a `sequence` type function to combine two reader monads into a single one, as such:

```js
const getNameParts = sequence(prop('name'), prop('lastName')) // Reader<Obj, [string,string]>
```

Then you can map the [string,string] to be a single string like in your add function

```js
const add = as => as.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item)
```

So if you can lift `add` into your reader monad's computational context (here using a proposed `map: ((a:A)=>B)=>(fa:F<A>)=>F<B>), then compose these operations:

```js
const buildNameFromObject = compose(getNameParts, map(add)) // Reader<Obj, string>
```

There we have it.

```js
const personsName = buildNameFromObject(someObject) // string
```

`fp-ts` is a library that provides everything I just mentioned, and using that library (with a few function name changes to align with fp-ts's vocabulary),

```js
import { reader, map } from 'fp-ts/lib/Reader'
import { sequenceT } from 'fp-ts/lib/Apply'
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/lib/pipeable'

const getNameParts = sequenceT(reader)(prop('name'), prop('lastName'))
const buildNameFromObject = pipe(getNameParts, map(add)) // Reader<Obj, string>, which is a fancy way of writing (o:Obj)=>string
buildNameFromObject({name:'Foo', lastName: 'Bar'}) // 'FooBar'
```

Your "fullName" function (`buildNameFromObject`) is now point free.

Comment: this was also very helpful, thanks for the thoughtful response!